# Flash Builder 4: mx:Button baseColor doesnt exist

Tags: flash, mxml, builder

Just wanted to add this here in case you are migrating your project from Flash Builder 4 Beta to Flash Builder 4 release.

I used a lot of mx:Buttons with the baseColor property, which now seems to be called chromeColor.

Answer (score 0):

use chromeColor instead.